# wxPython Button Background Image

Tags: image, button, wxpython, label, background-image

Can I create a button with text with a background image? In wxPython, there are certain functions which create buttons such as wx.lib.buttons.GenBitmapTextButton and other functions like that. I'm wondering if I can create a button with a fancy background image, as well as label text.

Comment: What's wrong with GenBitmapTextButton?  It seems like it would do what you are describing.

Comment: Nope. It just adds text beside the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built-in button that allows a background image underneath the text. You can probably look at one of the generic button widgets though and use them as a template. Basically you just need to draw the bitmap on and then draw text on top, probably by using wx.DC or wx.GCDC or similar. The generic buttons include such things as wx.lib.buttons, wx.lib.agw.aquabutton and wx.lib.platebtn among others.